# Android Fragment Dialog appearing to ignore layoutMargin or layoutWidth when using weightSum

Tags: android, dialog, fragment, android-dialogfragment

So I have DialogFragment that I create on button press used to select some info.

It seems no matter what I do if I am using weightSum's the diaglog will fill the screen even if I specified a layoutMargin or width of the parent layout.

This is on a Galaxy Tab running 3.2 and using the default Fragment library not the compatibility one.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks

Below is the layout I am using.

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutZoneDialog"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/modal_background"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/zoneSelectListView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:divider="@color/trans"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:padding="25dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0" >
    </ListView>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/zoneSelectImageLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".75"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/zoneSelectMainImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/black_50_percent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/zoneSelectCloseImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/modal_close"
            android:padding="15dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That's odd, because there is no matter for `LinearLayout` how you specify `weightSum`, whether explicitly with `android:weightSum` attribute or implicitly by specifying children's `layout_weight`'s. Here is the code, where weightSum is used:

            `float weightSum = mWeightSum > 0.0f ? mWeightSum : totalWeight;`

Comment: well I have tried your code above (layout) and on 3.2 Motorola Xoom works as is supposed to (not filling the whole screen). Therefore it leads me to think that perhaps is somehting in your code.

Comment: I think we have a Xoom laying around some where but my client has spec'ed Galaxy Tab's.

Answer (score 0):

Its  strange to me why `android:weightSum` is behaving unexpectedly while we using the Relative layout inside the Liner Layout .

i have tried your code and have able to manage with all Liner Layout ..

Try this ..

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutZoneDialog"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:weightSum="1"
 >

    <ListView
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:id="@+id/zoneSelectListView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0" >
    </ListView>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight=".75"
        android:id="@+id/zoneSelectImageLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/zoneSelectMainImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/zoneSelectCloseImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="15dp" 
            android:layout_gravity="right"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```